# Real hardware acceleration of vector images?

Tags: graphics-programming, svg, hardware-acceleration

Basically vector graphics have many advantages, especially that they scale very nicely.
So there are many reasons to use them in 3D and 2D games.
Is there any support for hardware accelerated vector graphics?

I know it's possible to parse SVGs and generate filled vertex buffers, but that has many disadvantages over e.g. parsing SVG into a small binary format and let the GPU handle it.
Of course the GPU would need to support most non-trivial SVG objects like paths, gradients and patterns to be actually usable.

Comment: You may find some information of interest in this [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191472/why-have-hardware-accelerated-vector-graphics-not-taken-off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually an NVidia extension to their cards that adds methods to the OpenGL API to deal directly with *Path Rendering*, AKA vector graphics: [NV Path Rendering](https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering).

I don't know how usable that driver is or if it is still being shipped with the newest cards. The OpenGL extension is dated of 2011.

Another option that provides hardware support is [OpenVG](https://www.khronos.org/openvg/), which was supposed to be the go-to of vector graphics. But this framework also doesn't seem to be moving forward very fast.